# Realm Local Database not working with Android Studio (Java)

Tags: java, android, mongodb, android-studio, realm

This is added to my build.gradle Project file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:10.15.0"
    }
}
```

This is added to my build.gradle Application file:

```
apply plugin: "realm-android"

implementation 'io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:10.15.0'
```

Error is:

```
> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class io.realm.processor.Utils (in unnamed module @0x319c63c6) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$ClassSymbol (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.code to unnamed module @0x319c63c6
```

Gradle Sync is successful but Build fails with error described. I am using AGP 8.0.0 and Gradle version 8.1 with Java version VERSION_11 and min sdk 24 and target sdk 33.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same problem.

I updated the Realm Gradle plugin to version 10.15.1:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0'
    classpath 'io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:10.15.1'
}
```

The error disappeared after a sync and rebuild of the project.

My Android studio Grandle JDK are 17.0.6.

I hope these tips are helpful to you.